# bpy scripting - custom video tools - error in new blender version - TypeError: '<' not supported

Tags: scripting, video

I have a custom python script for video editing, which speeds up my video workflow a ton

Script worked like a charm, but I installed a new (lts) Blender 2.93.1, and the script does not work any more

Script code:

```
    import bpy
    from math import ceil
    
    bl_info = {
        'name': 'VSE Tools Aum',
        'blender': (2, 80, 0),
        'description': "VSE tools: duplicate & move, apply speed control",
        'category': 'Video Tools',
    }
    
    
    class SCENE_PT_vse_tools_aum(bpy.types.Panel):
        bl_label = 'VSE Tools Aum'
        bl_idname = 'SCENE_PT_vse_tools_aum'
        bl_space_type = 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR'
        bl_region_type = 'UI'
        bl_category = 'Tool'
        # bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED', }
    
        def draw(self, context):
            layout = self.layout
            # scene = context.scene
            # curr_frame = context.frame_current
            # layout.prop()
            split = layout.split()
    
            col = split.column()
            col.label(text="Populate",)
    
            col = split.column()
            col.operator('sequencer.populate',
                         icon='FILE_SCRIPT',
                         text='Run',)
    
            row = layout.row()
            col = row.column()
            col.label(text="Speed",)
    
            col = row.column()
    
            col = row.column()
            col.operator('sequencer.apply_speed',
                         icon='FILE_SCRIPT',
                         text='Run')
    
    
    class SEQUENCER_OT_populate(bpy.types.Operator):
        '''with strip selected:
        1) jump playhead (2x),
        2) duplicate strip and
        3) snap it to playhead+/-offset'''
        bl_idname = 'sequencer.populate'
        bl_label = 'Populate'
        bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
        populate_steps = bpy.props.IntProperty(
            name='Populate steps',
            default=1,
            description="Run script x times",
        )
        snap_offset = bpy.props.IntProperty(
            name='Snap offset',
            default=16,
            description='Offset in frames',
        )
        jump_steps = bpy.props.IntProperty(
            name='Jump playhead steps',
            default=2,
            description="Jump playhead x times",
        )
    
        def execute(self, context):
            '''automate meta transition strip duplication and move
            strip_jump 2x ->
            duplicate selected meta strip ->
            slip meta strip to playhead minus snap offset
            '''
            # scene = bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
            scene = context.scene
            seq = bpy.ops.sequencer
    
            @classmethod
            def poll(cls, context):
                scene = context.scene
                seq = scene.sequence_editor
                if (seq and
                    seq.active_strip and
                        seq.active_strip.select):
                    print('populate poll executed')
                    return True
                return False
            '''if active_strip is none or no strip is selected, print message and exit'''
            if not scene.sequence_editor.active_strip or not scene.sequence_editor.active_strip.select:
                # print('NO active strip or NO strip selected, populate script cancelled')
                self.report(
                    {"ERROR_INVALID_INPUT"},
                    "NO active strip or NO strip selected, populate script cancelled",
                )
                return {'FINISHED'}
            '''if strip is selected, run populate magic'''
            if scene.sequence_editor.active_strip.select:
                '''TODO jump playhead only on movie clips'''
                '''loop execute function "populate_steps" times'''
                i = 0
                while i < self.populate_steps:
                    '''move playhead "jump_steps" times (go to the end of next strip)'''
                    j = 0
                    while j < self.jump_steps:
                        seq.strip_jump(next=True, center=False)
                        j += 1
                    '''find current playhead frame'''
                    current_frame = scene.frame_current
    
                    if seq.duplicate_move.poll():
                        seq.duplicate_move(
                            SEQUENCER_OT_duplicate={},
                            TRANSFORM_OT_seq_slide={
                                "value": (0, 0),
                                "snap": False,
                                "snap_target": "CLOSEST",
                                "snap_point": (0, 0, 0),
                                "snap_align": False,
                                "snap_normal": (0, 0, 0),
                                "release_confirm": False,
                                "use_accurate": False,
                            })
                    '''snap selected strip to current frame minus "snap_offset"'''
                    seq.snap(frame=current_frame-self.snap_offset)
                    i += 1
            # 'DEBUG', 'INFO', 'OPERATOR', 'PROPERTY', 'WARNING', 'ERROR', 'ERROR_INVALID_INPUT', 'ERROR_INVALID_CONTEXT', 'ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY'}) – Type
            self.report(
                {"INFO"},
                "Populate script executed, finishing",
            )
            return {'FINISHED'}
            # return {'CANCELLED'}
            # return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
            # return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
    
        def invoke(self, context, event):
            '''popup script dialog'''
            return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
    
    
    class SEQUENCER_OT_apply_speed(bpy.types.Operator):
        '''with strip selected:
        1) ui: enter speed: float x
        2) add speed_control
        3) movie strip: duration/x
        4) audio strip: duration/x & pitch=x
        5) playhead strip_jump(next=False)
        6) select 'remaining' strips, snap to playhead'''
        bl_idname = 'sequencer.apply_speed'
        bl_label = 'Speed Control'
        bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
        speed_factor = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
            name='Speed factor',
            default=4.0,
            description="Speed to apply to selected movie and sound clips",
        )
        add_modifiers = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
            name='Add modifiers',
            default=True,
            description=(
                "Add modifiers to movie clip: curves, hue correct, color balance"),
        )
    
        def execute(self, context):
            '''check if any sequence is selected'''
            sequences = [
                s for s in context.selected_sequences if s.type == 'SOUND' or s.type == 'MOVIE']
            # for strip in sequences:
            #     print('sequence: ', strip, strip.type)
            if not sequences:
                self.report(
                    {"ERROR_INVALID_INPUT"},
                    "No MOVIE or no SOUND strip selected, speed script cancelled",
                )
                return {"FINISHED"}
            sequences_length = len(sequences)
            '''2 sequences should be selected, MOVIE and SOUND'''
            if sequences_length > 2:
                self.report(
                    {"ERROR_INVALID_INPUT"},
                    "More than 2 sequences selected, speed script cancelled",
                )
                return {"FINISHED"}
            '''if 2 strips are selected, run speed apply magic'''
            sequence_editor = context.scene.sequence_editor
            sequencer = bpy.ops.sequencer
    
            sequencer.select_all(action="DESELECT")
    
            for strip in sequences:
                '''select SOUND strip, shorten duration / speed_factor'''
                if strip.type == 'SOUND':
                    selected_sound = strip
                    selected_sound.pitch = self.speed_factor
                    duration = ceil(
                        selected_sound.frame_final_duration / self.speed_factor)
                    selected_sound.frame_final_end = selected_sound.frame_final_start + duration
                    self.report(
                        {"INFO"},
                        "Speed script: sound shortened, pitch applied"
                    )
    
                '''select MOVIE strip, apply SPEED strip, shorten MOVIE duration / speed_factor
                TODO add modifiers curves, hue_correct, color_balance'''
                if strip.type == 'MOVIE':
                    strip.select = True
                    selected_movie = strip
    
                    print('selected_movie is ', selected_movie, selected_movie.type)
    
                    sequencer.effect_strip_add(type='SPEED')
                    speed_effect = sequence_editor.active_strip
                    speed_effect.use_default_fade = False
                    speed_effect.speed_factor = self.speed_factor
                    '''shorten MOVIE duration'''
                    duration = ceil(
                        selected_movie.frame_final_duration / self.speed_factor)
                    # selected_movie.frame_final_duration / speed_effect.speed_factor)
                    selected_movie.frame_final_end = selected_movie.frame_final_start + duration
                    speed_effect.select = False
                    self.report(
                        {"INFO"},
                        "Speed script: movie shortened, speed applied",
                    )
                    '''add modifiers'''
                    if self.add_modifiers:
                        sequence_editor.active_strip = selected_movie
                        sequencer.strip_modifier_add(type='CURVES')
                        sequencer.strip_modifier_add(type='HUE_CORRECT')
                        sequencer.strip_modifier_add(type='COLOR_BALANCE')
                        self.report(
                            {"INFO"},
                            "Speed script: added modifiers curves, hue_correct, color_balance",
                        )
    
            return {"FINISHED"}
    
        def invoke(self, context, event):
            return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
    
    
    classes = (SCENE_PT_vse_tools_aum,
               SEQUENCER_OT_populate,
               SEQUENCER_OT_apply_speed,
               )
    
    register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        register()
```

Error when i hit 'run' button:

```
    Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\chist\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\VSEToolsAum.py", line 113, in execute
        while i < self.populate_steps:
    TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and '_PropertyDeferred'
    
    location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Also, when I hit 'run' button, previously (when script was working ok) there was pop-up window, with property fields to set, now there is pop-up window with name of script (ie 'populate'), and 'ok' button

obviously, problem is this line:

```
'while i < self.populate_steps:'
i tried casting into integer:
'while i < int(self.populate_steps):', did not work
```

Was Blender scripting updated somehow ?
what must i change to make my precious oh precious script be happy again ?

Comment: As of Blender 2.93 you have to use annotations. Support is dropped for 'non-annotation' properties, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/228128/31447 Does that help?

Comment: thank you for your reply;
will check in future, most probably this is the cause of the error;
for now, i dl blender 2.91.0 version, and will use that, since it works as expected;